# refresh button for datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i need help in refresh the datagridview. I create a Update button and show button but it didn't refresh. but i check in my database access it update successful

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form2
Public con As OleDbConnection
Public da As OleDbDataAdapter
Public ds As New DataSet
Public cmd As OleDbCommand
Public dr As OleDbDataReader
Dim count As Integer = 100
Dim ID As String

Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Try
        'Establish connection
        con = New OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\Users\m_j_g\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DatabaseApplication\Department.accdb")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnShow_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShow.Click
    Try
        'establish connection
        con = New OleDbConnection("provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source = C:\Users\m_j_g\OneDrive\Documents\Database1.accdb")
        'execute sql query
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from table1", con)
        'Fill Dataset
        da.Fill(ds, "table1")
        'put data from dataset to datagridview
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    con = New OleDbConnection("provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source = C:\Users\m_j_g\OneDrive\Documents\Database1.accdb")


    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("Update table1 set SurName='" & TextBox2.Text & "', FirstName='" & TextBox3.Text & "' where EmailAddress='" & TextBox5.Text & "'", con)
        'Execute UPDATE Query
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Record Updated Successfully..." & Chr(13) & "Email Address: " & TextBox5.Text & Chr(13) & "SurName: " & TextBox2.Text & Chr(13) & "FirstName: " & TextBox3.Text)
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I am newbie in programming Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rebind the Grid after performing the update, Follow these steps this may help you:

1. Define a Method for binding the giridiew, this will populate the grid with values from the DB:

   ```
   Public Sub bindMyGrid()
      con = New OleDbConnection("provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source = C:\Users\m_j_g\OneDrive\Documents\Database1.accdb")
      da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from table1", con)
      da.Fill(ds, "table1")
      DataGridView1.Rows.Clear() '<-- new line added
      DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
   End Sub
   ```
2. Call the method in the click event of the show button to populate the grid:

   ```
     Private Sub btnShow_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShow.Click
       Try
          bindMyGrid()
       Catch ex As Exception
       ' handle error here 
       End Try
     End Sub
   ```
3. Perform the update operation on update button click, and call the method again to get the latest values.

   ```
     Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
         Try
           'Perform the update operations here 
           ' Call  bindMyGrid() to rebind the grid
           bindMyGrid() 'this will populate the new value to the grid.
         Catch ex As Exception
           'Handle error here
         End Try
     End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
but i have another problem. the 1st view of the datagridview didn't close. It remains and add additional view

Comment: Sorry i don't get you... what you mean by first view?

Comment: it refresh the update i input. but the old data show in datagridview remains.

Comment: {5678 Guevarra Vince Andrew example456@gmail.com 456
1234 Gonzales Mike         Stephen example123@gmail.com 123}
{5678 Guevarra Vince Andrew example456@gmail.com 456
1234 Gonzales Christian Stephen example123@gmail.com 123}

Comment: it show like that. i update the name of Gonzales Mike Stephen to Gonzales Christian Stephen. but the last data of datagridview remains in the Gride

Comment: @M.J see [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217175/vb-net-clear-datagridview?answertab=votes#tab-top). it may help you.

Comment: hey guys :) thanks for the help.
i use  `Call CType(myDataGrid.DataSource, DataTable).Rows.Clear()`
but this statement needs to click button to clear not to refresh. but this statement help me